# Statistically differentiate temperature sensor readings and dynamic temperature setpoint + historical data

Tags: automation, statistics, time-series, data-science, building

I am currently working on a project where I would like to statistically differentiate a temperature sensors readings, from setpoint temperature readings within the traffic of a building automation system.

To elaborate more on which type of problem I am trying to solve here, let us say that I am observing the historical data from sensors recording different data for a common experiment.

If I do not have the title of each chart, how could I, after recognizing a chart as a temperature related one, say for sure if it is a reading or a dynamic setpoint? To add, let us consider a temperature sensor that has precision reaching only integers (no decimal number included).

Thank you for your time.

Respectfully,
Maher.

Comment: Hi Maher, this is an interesting question, but more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com. That said, in a broad sense my advice is to approach such problems via Bayesian inference. Essentially you can build models of the observable variables as a function of the unobserved variables which you are trying to infer, and then use Bayesian inference to derive distributions over the unobserved variables. Of course there are many details to sort out. See e.g. my dissertation http://riso.sourceforge.net/docs/dodier-dissertation.pdf especially Chapter 6 which presents some simple models for sensors.

Comment: Thank you @RobertDodier i will take the time to read your dissertation and come back to you if i have some doubts.  Much appreciated